# AngularFire - $firebaseArray can $add but not read

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I feel like I must be missing something very basic. Here is a portion of my service:

```
angular.module('fire')
  .constant('FIREBASE_URI', 'https://___.firebaseio.com/')

  .factory('syncArraySvc', function(FIREBASE_URI, $firebaseArray) {

    var buildingsUri = FIREBASE_URI + "buildings";
    var buildings = $firebaseArray(new Firebase(buildingsUri));
    console.log(buildings);

    var getBuildings = function() {
      return buildings;
    };
    var addBuilding = function(item) {
      buildings.$add(item);
    };
    return {
      getBuildings: getBuildings,
      addBuilding: addBuilding
    };
  });
```

The console.log in the middle of that just returns an empty array. If I try to call the `syncArraySvc.getBuildings()` function from another controller, I also get an empty array. Somehow, `$add(item)` works, as does `syncArraySvc.addBuilding(item)`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers helped get me pointed in the right direction.

The [API documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray) has a code sample that doesn't seem to need the data to be wrapped in a promise:

```
var list = $firebaseArray(new Firebase(URL));
$scope.list = list;
```

However, it does point out that you can use the [`$loaded`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-loaded) promise to be notified when the data is loaded. This is how I got it to work in my project:

```
syncArraySvc.getBuildings().$loaded(function(data) {
  $scope.buildings = data;
});
```

I tried replicating this in a fresh project, and it consistently worked without the `$loaded` wrapper, like they show in the first example. It makes sense to me that the `$loaded` wrapper would be required. I don't understand how it could be working in the first example without it.

Comment: The `$loaded` promise resolves when the *initial* data has loaded. It does *not* resolve when additional items are added to the array.  All that you need to do is `$scope.buildings = $firebaseArray(new Firebase(buildingsUri))`. And please don't use `console.log` for debugging AngularFire data, it easily leads to misunderstandings. Instead, just put this somewhere in your view: `<pre>buildings | json</pre>`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen does my above answer will ensure the data has been added or not..i believe it will surely work and show updated data

Comment: To properly extend a `$firebaseArray`, read: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/extending-services.html#section-firebasearray

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for the tip on debugging. Going back to the code after a couple days, I tried using the suggested format and it rendered in the view correctly while `console.log` still returned an empty array. If you'd like to post your comment as an answer I can mark it as correct so that other people can see where the actual issue was.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at $add `$firebaseArray`, It does create new item & add it into to `$firebaseArray` as like we have `buildings`. But as soon as you add item to ``$firebaseArray` it doesn't get added instantly. It get added when the $add promise get resolved.

I think you are doing correct thing, only you need call `syncArraySvc.addBuilding(item)` method on success of `$add` promise.

To make this approach you need to return a promise from the service method like

```
var addBuilding = function(item) {
  return buildings.$add(item);
};
```

And then the caller function will take that promise and on resolve of it, he will call `syncArraySvc.addBuilding(item)` method that have assurity that items has added in `buildings` array.

```
syncArraySvc.addBuilding({foo: "bar"}).then(function(addedItem){
    console.log(addedItem);
    console.log(syncArraySvc.addBuilding(item)); //this will show you updated list
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) service inside the getBuildings function or rather when you call it. It probably takes a little while before data is returned.