# Data request is sometimes asynchronous

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, firebase

This is a follow-up to a question I posted earlier today. I'm going through [this book on using AngularJS with Firebase](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/data-oriented-development-angularjs), which lead me to post [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30943734/angularfire-firebasearray-can-add-but-not-read). I found a solution, but what I still don't understand is that the example in the [API Documentation for a `$firebaseArray`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray) doesn't seem to be handling it as an asynchronous request.

```
var list = $firebaseArray(new Firebase(URL));

// add an item
list.$add({ foo: "bar" }).then(...);

// remove an item
list.$remove(2).then(...);

// make the list available in the DOM
$scope.list = list;
```

Also, the example from the books seems to treat the request synchronously as well.

```
# Service
var buildingsUri = FIREBASE_URI + '/buildings';
var ref = new Firebase(buildingsUri);
var buildings = $firebaseArray(ref);

var getBuildings = function () {
  return buildings;
};

...
# Controller
$scope.buildings = syncArraySvc.getBuildings();
```

How is it that `$scope.list` in the first example and `$scope.buildings` in the second example could be properly populated with data when they haven't checked to make sure the request has completed?

Comment: i assume firebase is returning a $q promise. These typically get updated to also contain the result after the request is completed. When the digest runs,the view would then be updated with said data.

Comment: @KevinB I think I'm following. Based on the [documentation on the $q service from Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q), the `$firebaseArray()` must be wrapping the `then` and other callbacks in order to return the requested data without requiring a callback in the client code, does that sound right?

Comment: No, i'm pretty sure it's just returning a $q promise. console.log it to be sure, you should see more than just your data on it. It can't just update the var to contain something else, it's still going to be whatever base object it returned to you.

Answer (score 1):

The $add and $remove methods return promises. The $firebaseArray() method returns an array with some special functions and properties added. Neither $add or $remove require the data to be loaded locally or depend on the state of the data, so they can be called synchronously. The data is still downloaded asynchronously, of course. So, for example:

```
var list = $firebaseArray(new Firebase(URL));

// add an item
list.$add({ foo: "bar" }).then(function(ref) {
   console.log('added', ref.key());
});

// remove an item
list.$remove(2).then(function(ref) {
   console.log('removed', ref.key());
});

console.log('list current contains', list.length, 'items');

list.$loaded(function() {
   console.log('after loading initial data, the list contains', list.length, 'items');
});
```

Assuming the list contains 10 items at load time, and that list is not changed remotely during this code execution, we would see output similar to the following:

```
list currently contains 0 items
after loading initial state, the list contains 10 items
added abc123
removed xyz456
```

Additionally, I'd note that this code is probably superfluous. Usually when we see code like this, it's because devs are trying to turn Firebase into a CRUD model. You can probably just return $firebaseArray() there instead and use the existing methods like $getRecord(), et al, instead of artificially wrapping the API in your service.

Comment: [In a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30943734/angularfire-firebasearray-can-add-but-not-read), someone commented that using `console.log` to debug AngularFire data was not a good idea. I understand that `$add` and `$remove` methods, because they use the standard promise syntax with `.then`. In your example you use `$loaded` with `list`, but if you assign `list` to the scope, with `$scope.list = list` for example, it would render the list items correctly. Even though putting `console.log` after that assignment would return an empty array. That's what I'm not getting.

Comment: It will be empty until the data is downloaded locally. Also, there was a bug in the $loaded method when using $extend in the 1.1.0 & 1.1.1 releases. It was fixed in 1.1.2